Why not allowing people to delete their own question?
Sometimes I posts questions I thought it good and still do now, but it has been down voted very badly, for example How slow can DDR4 RAM be?
I don't understand why is this a bad question since I thought it will help others to understand the how the ram modules on motherboard works, but still it got a lot downvote.
Then I thought I should delete it as it has been down voted(meaning it's not helpful to other people) but then Super User won't allow me to do so because https://superuser.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

It is what it is. Next time please read [ask]

Deleting a question because you’re unhappy with the reception is very rarely the solution. It’s much easier to address the reason the question received downvotes. The reason question once they are answered cannot be deleted by the author is to prevent the author from asking questions and removing the question after they were helped.

But since the post has got a lot down vote that means it's not gonna be helpful for other people right? So why leave it there so other people can waste time browsing it? Why not just give the author of the answer credit even if the quastion was deleted?

Also I don't even see how am I suppose to improve the post, I'm a just suppose to sit there and let it eat my credit?

@james—Even if you delete the question, it still counts against your ability to submit new questions. Deleting your question yourself is a significant decision and should be avoided whenever possible. "But since the post has got a lot of downvotes, that means it's not gonna be helpful for other people, right?" - If it received an answer, then that answer might be helpful to others. If you don't edit the question, those votes can never be reversed.

Taking example of https://superuser.com/questions/1861134/how-slow-can-ddr4-ram-be how can I improve it? I tried to do so by following the manual but still didn't work.

This question is similar to: Can I not delete my own questions, after answers were posted?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Questions that have answers are protected from the author deleting the question, in the hopes that someone else has the same question and the answer potentially helps.
Relative XKCD:

